# What is lnprototest exactly? Can it be used to test an individual Lightning implementation or just interoperability between implementations?

Tags: core-lightning, testing, lightning-rfc

What is [lnprototest](https://medium.com/blockstream/announcing-the-lnprototest-alpha-release-f43f46f2c05) exactly? Can it be used to test an individual Lightning implementation or just interoperability between implementations? What does an implementation need to do to use lnprototest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rusty Russell discussed lnprototest ([repo link](https://github.com/rustyrussell/lnprototest)) during the August 2020 [Sydney Socratic Seminar](https://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/sydney-bitcoin-meetup/2020-08-25-socratic-seminar/).

What is lnprototest exactly?

> It is a pure Python3 test system and some packages to interface with
> the spec that currently live in the c-lightning repository. You run
> lnprototest and it has these scripts that go “I will send this” and
> you will send back this. It can keep state and does some quite
> sophisticated things. It has a whole heap of scaffolding to understand
> commitment transactions, anchor outputs and a whole heap of other
> things. Then you write these scripts that say “If I send this it
> should send this” or “If I send this instead…”. You create this DAG, a
> graph of possible things that could happen and it runs through all of
> them and checks that happens.

Can it be used to test an individual Lightning implementation or just interoperability between implementations?

> It is really good for protocol development too not just testing
> existing stuff. When you want to modify the spec you can write that
> half and run it against your own node.

Since writing this answer a [PR](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/4444) in the c-lightning repo from Lisa Neigut was merged to run lnprototest with every c-lightning CI build.

What does an implementation need to do to use lnprototest?

> They need their own runner. Take the c-lightning one, it fires up a
> bitcoind in regtest mode and fires up a c-lightning node. It is kind
> of dumb. You have to have c-lightning run in developer mode because it
> uses some weird hacks. We are slowly pulling those out. Ideally you’d
> be able to run it in any off the shelf implementation. You have to get
> your hands dirty a bit and write some Python for your implementation,
> that is true.